# Visual Studio C++ : Getting Unresolved tokens and unresolved link. What should I do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to use SQLite but I get unresolved-* errors. Here is the summary of what I have done:

Here are three directories:

SourceFiles

```
-->include
-->src
-->sqlite3
```

I have added all above three directories to:

```
Project Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories
```

Then In my main.cpp file, I added the below line:

```
#include<SQLite/SQliteCpp.h> // this inclusion is correct
```

But I get errors as follows:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003DF) "public: virtual __thiscall SQLite::Column::~Column(void)" (??1Column@SQLite@@$$FUAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall SQLite::Column::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EColumn@SQLite@@$$FUAEPAXI@Z)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003EE) "public: __thiscall SQLite::Statement::Ptr::Ptr(class SQLite::Statement::Ptr const &)" (??0Ptr@Statement@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV012@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall SQLite::Column::Column(class SQLite::Column const &)" (??0Column@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003EF) "public: __thiscall SQLite::Statement::Ptr::~Ptr(void)" (??1Ptr@Statement@SQLite@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall SQLite::Column::Column(class SQLite::Column const &)" (??0Column@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SQLite::Statement::Ptr::Ptr(class SQLite::Statement::Ptr const &)" (??0Ptr@Statement@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV012@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall SQLite::Column::Column(class SQLite::Column const &)" (??0Column@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SQLite::Statement::Ptr::~Ptr(void)" (??1Ptr@Statement@SQLite@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall SQLite::Column::Column(class SQLite::Column const &)" (??0Column@SQLite@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
```

Comment: You are including source (cpp) file instead of header? Last time i used sqlite, its "amalgamation" version had normal header.

Comment: Sorry It was a typo in question. No I had included header... (.h)

Comment: Have you added all relevant .c/.cpp files to your solution? (from src and sqlite3 directories)

Comment: I have just added the above three directories and nothing else :|

Comment: @MostafaTalebi I haven't used SQLite in a while, but aren't you supposed to link against a sqlite.lib or something? Or is there a header-only version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the standard sqlite source distribution, there should be a .c or .cpp file 
inside your sqlite3 directory.  That file needs to be included in the project and compiled along with your source.   The other possibility is that you may have received the sqlite3 headers with a .lib file -- if that's the case, then you'll need to link the library along with your project.

The reason you're getting those errors is because your header file (sqlite3.h) is referencing functions/symbols/etc. for which there are no definitions.   So, that's why you need to either include the .c/.cpp file along with your project (so that you provide the definitions), or else link to a precompiled .lib that basically does the same thing.

Comment: i check it and then report it here

Comment: By the way, here is a project of mine that uses SQLite3: https://github.com/Amadeus-/isxSQLite .  While the project may not be of much use to you (it's going to create a DLL "extension" to another piece of software), it should compile out-of-the-box.   Perhaps then you can see how it's linked/organized and determine what you need to do in order to fix your project.